# Pass a JSON Array for POST request using Rest Assured based on the following JSON

Tags: rest-assured

I am new to Rest Assured, Please can someone help me to create the body request from the following output:

```
{
    "CustomerID": "539177",
    "ReminderTitle": "Demo Reminder Tds",
    "ReminderDescription": "xyz Reminder",
    "ReminderLocation": "New Delhi",
    "ReminderDate": "2020-03-27",
    "ReminderTime": "15:33",
    "attendees": [{
        "CustomerContactID": "122"
    }]
}
```

Example :

```
Map <String, String> body = new HashMap <String, String> ();

body.put("CustomerID", CustomerID);
body.put("ReminderTitle", "Demo Reminder Tds");
body.put("ReminderDescription", "xyz Reminder");
body.put("ReminderLocation", "New Delhi");
body.put("ReminderDate", "2020-03-27");
body.put("ReminderTime", "15:33");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Map<String, Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
map.put("CustomerID", "539177");
map.put("ReminderTitle", "Demo Reminder Tds");
map.put("ReminderDescription", "xyz Reminder");
map.put("ReminderLocation", "New Delhi");
map.put("ReminderDate", "2020-03-27");
map.put("ReminderTime", "15:33");
map.put("attendees", Arrays.asList(new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>() {
    {
        put("CustomerContactID", "122");
    }
}));
```

Use the below to just print out the output ( you don't have to necessarily )

```
String abc = new ObjectMapper().writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(map);
System.out.println(abc);
```

And to use it with Rest Assured

```
given().body(map).when().post()
```

Comment: My CustomerID and CustomerContactID are coming as string so it is not able to pass it correctly. Showing {"status":"0","message":"Invalid format for : CustomerContactID"}  String customerIDValue = PropFileHandler.readProperty("CustomerID");
HeaderConfigs header = new HeaderConfigs(); 
PostAPIBuilders builder = new PostAPIBuilders();
Response response = RestAssured.given().headers(header.defaultHeaders()).body(builder.postCustomerReminder(customerIDValue, CustomerContactID))
.when().post(APIPath.apiPath.CUSTOMERREMINDERAPI);

Comment: If you need them as int then just remove the quotes, `map.put("CustomerID", 539177)` and `put("CustomerContactID", 122);`The sample JSON you provided had those values as strings so I framed it as is

Comment: I am passing it as string.public Map<String, Object> postCustomerReminder(String CustomerID, final String map2){
Map<String, Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
  map.put("CustomerID", CustomerID);
  map.put("ReminderTitle", "Demo Reminder Tds");
  map.put("ReminderDescription", "xyz Reminder");
map.put("ReminderLocation", "New Delhi");
map.put("ReminderDate", "2020-03-27");
  map.put("ReminderTime", "15:33");
  map.put("attendees", Arrays.asList(new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>() {
      {
          put("CustomerContactID", map2);
      }
  }));
  return map; 
 }

Comment: What worked for me as well was: JSONObject map = new JSONObject();
  map.put("CustomerID", CustomerID);
  map.put("ReminderTitle", "Demo Reminder Tds");
  map.put("ReminderDescription", "xyz Reminder");
  map.put("ReminderLocation", "New Delhi");
  map.put("ReminderDate", "2020-03-27");
  map.put("ReminderTime", "15:33");
  map.put("attendees", Arrays.asList(new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>() {
   {
    put("CustomerContactID", CustomerContactID);
   }
  }));
  
  return map;

Answer (score 0):

Rest Assured accepts String objects in .body(String body) method. But for POST and PUT methods only. Check the [documentation](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/io.rest-assured/rest-assured/3.1.1/io/restassured/specification/RequestSpecification.html#body-java.lang.String-)

Therefore you can just pass the output you received.

```
        String requestBody = "{ \"CustomerID\" : \"539177\", " +
            "\"ReminderTitle\" : \"Demo Reminder Tds\", " +
            "\"ReminderDescription\" : \"xyz Reminder\", " +
            "\"ReminderLocation\" : \"New Delhi\", " +
            "\"ReminderDate\" : \"2020-03-27\", " +
            "\"ReminderTime\" : \"15:33\", " +
            "\"attendees\" : [{\"CustomerContactID\" : \"122\"}] }";
```

BUT you have to use escape characters in the output String.
Then just pass the requestBody;

```
    given()
        .body(requestBody)
        .when()
        .post(URL);
```